# Xml / Newtonsoft Json Object Seralization in wp7 Mango

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

By using Newtonsoft json serializer and xml Serrializer how can i serialize and deserialize objects. Pls send me the method to acheve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, you might want to elaborate.

You can deserialize an object to/from JSON using `JsonConvert`:

```
ObjectToDeserialize value = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectToDeserialize>(jsonString);
```

Comment: 1, How to serilaize& Dezerilaize object using Newtonsoft Json Serializer and also i need to know 2. How to serialize and deserialize an object using XML Serialization in WP7. If possible please guide me about choosing a good alternative for my application.

Comment: ie wether i go with json serialization or xml serialization . plz help me rechard

Comment: @stezma - I'd recommend sticking with JSON as it's smaller and JSON.NET is faster than the built in XML serializer.

Comment: Pls demonstrate the method for deserilaizng the Object too, by using Newtonsoft JsonSerializer. thanks in advance.

Comment: The supplied code _does_ deserialize. To _serialize_ change it to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`